# Going from $\frac{y^{-3}}{-3}=\frac{1}{2}x^2+c$ to $y(x)=(c-\frac{3}{2}x^2)^{\frac{-1}{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation

$$\frac{y^{-3}}{-3}=\frac{1}{2}x^2+c$$

and I need to obtain this

$$y(x)=\left(c-\frac{3}{2}x^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$

But I am not sure how to obtain it.

I start by multiplying both sides by  minus three and I obtain

$$ y^{-3}=\frac{-3}{2}x^{2}-3c $$

I am not sure where to go next...

Please, could anyone try to help me get that expression?

P.S. Would it be possible to obtain this expression by using Matlab or Mathematica?

By using Wolfram Alpha Pro Premium (online website)

I obtain this expression

$$ y=\frac{(-1)^\frac{2}{3}*\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{-2c-x^{2}}} $$

I don't even know what to think...

Comment: Replace $-3c$ by a new constant $c'$ and take cube root on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

WolframAlpha treats the problem as an algebraic equation over the complex numbers, where you have 3 branches of the cube root. Thus the strange constants that would simplify under a real-numbers setting.

Apart from that, all formulas are equivalent and only differ in how the constant is parametrized, as @Koro commented, also using that $u^{-\frac13}=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{u}}$.